# What does the IS_ALIGNED macro in the linux kernel do?

Tags: linux, macros, kernel, memory-alignment

I've been trying to read the implementation of a kernel module, and I'm stumbling on this piece of code.

```
unsigned long addr = (unsigned long) buf;

if (!IS_ALIGNED(addr, 1 << 9)) {
    DMCRIT("@%s in %s is not sector-aligned. I/O buffer must be sector-aligned.", name, caller);
    BUG();
}
```

The IS_ALIGNED macro is defined in the kernel source as follows:

```
#define IS_ALIGNED(x, a)        (((x) & ((typeof(x))(a) - 1)) == 0)
```

I understand that data has to be aligned along the size of a datatype to work, but I still don't understand what the code does.

It left-shifts 1 by 9, then subtracts by 1, which gives 111111111. Then 111111111 does bitwise-and with x.

Why does this code work? How is this checking for byte alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In systems programming it is common to need a memory address to be aligned to a certain number of bytes -- that is, several lowest-order bits are zero.

Basically, !IS_ALIGNED(addr, 1 << 9) checks whether addr is on a 512-byte (2^9) boundary (the last 9 bits are zero). This is a common requirement when erasing flash locations because flash memory is split into large blocks which must be erased or written as a single unit.

Another application of this I ran into. I was working with a certain DMA controller which has a modulo feature. Basically, that means you can allow it to change only the last several bits of an address (destination address in this case). This is useful for protecting memory from mistakes in the way you use a DMA controller. Problem it, I initially forgot to tell the compiler to align the DMA destination buffer to the modulo value. This caused some incredibly interesting bugs (random variables that have nothing to do with the thing using the DMA controller being overwritten... sometimes).

As far as "how does the macro code work?", if you subtract 1 from a number that ends with all zeroes, you will get a number that ends with all ones. For example, 0b00010000 - 0b1 = 0b00001111. This is a way of creating a binary mask from the integer number of required-alignment bytes. This mask has ones only in the bits we are interested in checking for zero-value. After we AND the address with the mask containing ones in the lowest-order bits we get a 0 if any only if the lowest 9 (in this case) bits are zero.

"Why does it need to be aligned?": This comes down to the internal makeup of flash memory. Erasing and writing flash is a much less straightforward process then reading it, and typically it requires higher-than-logic-level voltages to be supplied to the memory cells. The circuitry required to make write and erase operations possible with a one-byte granularity would waste a great deal of silicon real estate only to be used rarely. Basically, designing a flash chip is a statistics and tradeoff game (like anything else in engineering) and the statistics work out such that writing and erasing in groups gives the best bang for the buck.

At no extra charge, I will tell you that you will be seeing a lot of this type of this type of thing if you are reading driver and kernel code. It may be helpful to familiarize yourself with the contents of this article (or at least keep it around as a reference): https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: Yes, the kernel module is being used to create a writeback SSD cache for a HDD. So the application uses flash memory. I understand that flash must be erased between writes. Can you elaborate on why there is a need to make sure the last few bits are zero?

Comment: Sorry, I can see why the memory address has to have the last 9 entries be zero in order for the memory address to be aligned on the 512 byte boundary. Do you know whether it is the block or the page size that is 512 bytes?

Comment: The terminology hat is being used in the error message is "sector-aligned". I keep forgetting the difference in definitions between block vs sector vs page. Looking it up just now, a page is the smallest WRITE unit. A sector or block is the smallest ERASE unit.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much

Comment: @user6337 see additions to answer. The article I linked should be helpful.